# ECR lifecycle policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, docker-image, amazon-ecr

In our ECR, we are having multiple repositories for each microservice.

Service 1

Service 2

Service 3

while building the code (for anyone service), creating an image out of it and pushing to ECR, we tag it with keyword - **dev** and **build-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX**.

If we do this process again, the new image will be tagged as above, but the above image (which is now previous) will be only tagged as **build-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX**.

How do I set lifecycle policy to remove only those image which is tagged only as **build-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX**

I set below policy, but during a test run, I can see that it is also picking up those images which are tagged as **dev** which I don't want to delete.

**dev** tagged image will always be present with **build-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX**

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      },
      "selection": {
        "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
        "countNumber": 5,
        "tagStatus": "tagged",
        "tagPrefixList": [
          "build"
        ]
      },
      "description": "remove images starting with build",
      "rulePriority": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

In the same repo, I also push test and UAT images with respective tags (**test** & **uat**), with the exactly above process (with **build-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX** as well) and don't want to delete them too.

Comment: The `dev` tag can't exist on two images at the same time. I am not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Obvious solution would be to alter your tagging convention and tag "dev" builds with some other word not containing "build"

Comment: Hi Jordanm, Yes ofcourse dev tag can't exist on two images. If I build first time an image - it will be with two tags - dev and build-XXX-XX and if I build again a second image - now this will be tagged with dev and build-YY-YYY and earlier image only remains with build-XXX-XXX. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

> An image that matches the tagging requirements of a rule cannot be
> expired by a rule with a lower priority.

If you want to keep one `dev` tagged image, you have to add additional rule for that, set the highest priority for that rule (I set 10 in the example below) and decrease priority of your `build` tagged  rule (I set 100), for example:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rulePriority": 10,
      "description": "Remove dev except one",
      "selection": {
        "tagStatus": "tagged",
        "tagPrefixList": [
          "dev"
        ]
        "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
        "countNumber": 1
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      }
    },
    {
      "rulePriority": 100,
      "description": "Remove images starting with build",
      "selection": {
        "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
        "countNumber": 5,
        "tagStatus": "tagged",
        "tagPrefixList": [
          "build"
        ]
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The same way add rules for tags `uat` and `test` with different priority (20 and 30 for example), but higher than `build` one.